# Development Environment for Java Expression Language (JEXL)

Tags: java, ide

I am looking for a good way to develop JEXL code and cannot find any examples online. Preferably this would be through the use of an IDE, though a text editor such as atom with syntax highlighting for JEXL would work if no IDE supports JEXL.

Purchasing or creating such an environment are acceptable, though not preferred.